# Can a html frameset frame tell its position on the page / in the window (through javascript environment variable or otherwise)

Tags: javascript, html, frameset

Pesudo code:

```
If you are a frame that touches the right and the bottom of the window (/page/tab) 
(, then it is likely that you are a content area...)

If i am a frame that is on the left outline of window and of other frames 
(, then it is likely that i am a menu...)
```

In JS words:

i know    self.location.match(/(menu)/g)

- and  window.name.match(/(menu)/g)   , thanks @James K.

but what if both is not set?

is there anything like **"self.position"**?

```
if(self.position.LeftNeighborOfOtherFrames&&self.position.window=left){...assume self is menu....}
else if(self.position = atRightOutlineOfWindow && atBottomOutlineOfWindow){...assuming content|page....} 
else if(self.positon.window=top){...assuming header...}
else if(self.position.window=bottom){...assuming footer...}
```

*i know frames are not modern/historic - when this is not your thing please suggest a retro-section to stackoverflow rather than voting away the question?*

Answer (score 1):

In the way you're describing, no, you can't.

Well, you can, but if you want to do it *entirely* in javascript, you're going to have a challenge accounting for all of the variables involved (browser inconsistency, many different screen resolutions, workstations with several displays...).  More discussion on that under "Difficult Answer" below.

## Easy Answer:

The easiest way to do what you're trying to do is not entirely javascript, but rather the addition of the name parameter to the frame tag.  So, as a very simplistic example:

```
<frameset rows="40%, 60%">
    <frame src="top.html" name="top">
    <frame src="bottom.html" name="bottom">
</frameset>
```

From the perspective of the page running within each frame, the frame is the `window` object.  Within each frame, you can call `window.name` and get the name you assigned.

That is, `window.name` will return "top" in the frame that has the name, "top".

I should probably note that this is *not* actually part of a javascript standard, but it works on all of the major browsers.

## Difficult Answer:

You asked for a way to do this entirely in javascript.  The only way I can figure to do that is to get the screen position of the parent window, the screen position of each frame, and possibly the total resolution of the display, and then effectively guess about each of the frames. Since I can't seriously recommend guessing, I don't actually consider it a viable option.  But, if you can't edit the frame names and really need an all-javascript solution, that's probably it.

I can elaborate on that if you need it, but it's definitely not a preferred method, especially in comparison to just naming the frames.

Comment: Thanks! Difficult answer would be great since name/filename aren't set often

Comment: I may need a more information, then.  What is known for certain about the situation?  Do you have control over the frameset?  Can you run scripts on that page?  Is the frameset page on the same domain?  (Cross-domain permissions between frames are very intentionally difficult.)  Do you know the frame layout?  Or, it is just a situation where a page _could_ be in a frame, and you want to make a reasonable guess which frame is most likely?

Comment: thanks:)  @james-k     Yes, a situation where a page could be in a frame, and a reasonable guess would come in handy. Not yet cross domain.  I dont know how to check the frameset page from a frame's point of view and didn't yet expect this to be possible without JS.

Comment: Well, at the moment it's not possible without JS.  And, until something similar to JS rises up, it won't be.  As far the the client is concerned, there are scripts (like JS) and markup (HTML, for this discussion we'll include CSS, etc.).  Markup defines how something should be.  Scripts allow you to inquire how things actually are. 

I still don't have enough information to give you a better answer. In general, browsers avoid making the parent available to the frame, because that has enormous security implications.

Comment: :) More preceisely yes, "make a reasonable guess which frame is most likely". Yes, just within one domain yet.

(Actually we understood all earlier as in "yes, 'Difficult Answer' please"  I guess you missed the double-negative in my last sentence? i didnt plan to use any VBS. )
Thanks